# Absolute position and Overflow:hidden

Tags: html, css

```
<div id="parent" style="overflow:hidden; position:relative;">
  <div id="child" style="position:absolute;">
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to show child element which is bigger than it's parent element, but without removing overflow:hidden; is this possible?
parent element has `position:relative;`
child element gets stripped as soon as it's out of it's parents borders.

(elements have additional css defined I just put style attributes for clearness)

Comment: have a look at [this link](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/uLeWp/2/), is this what you want?   It's basically what you're already doing.

Comment: You have poor example code. This: `"child element gets stripped as soon as it's out of it's parents borders"` doesn't happen with your current code, see: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/wPPH5/ Add a better example.

Comment: not unless you specify a height on the parent to make it big enough to fit the child. `overflow:hidden` is in contrast with your requirement. It's either one or the other, not both.

Comment: sorry I forgot that the parent container is relatively positioned.

Comment: While this may not do what you want, using `position: fixed` instead of `absolute` will break it out of the container.

Comment: @Blazemonger which is a disaster if the layout is dynamic or it scrolls.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

It's completely impossible to do what you want with both `overflow: hidden` and `position: relative` on the parent `div`.. instead you can introduce an extra child `div` and move `overflow: hidden` to that.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/TFTnU/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="hideOverflow">
        <div style="width:1000px;background:#ccc">sdfsd</div>
    </div>
  <div id="child">overflow "visible"</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#parent {
    position:relative;
    background:red;
    width:100px;
    height:100px
}
#child {
    position:absolute;
    background:#f0f;
    width:300px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0
}
#hideOverflow {
    overflow: hidden
}
```

```css
#parent {
  position: relative;
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px
}

#child {
  position: absolute;
  background: #f0f;
  width: 300px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0
}

#hideOverflow {
  overflow: hidden
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="hideOverflow">
    <div style="width:1000px;background:#ccc">sdfsd</div>
  </div>
  <div id="child">overflow "visible"</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note that if you remove position: relative property, the child can overflow.

Comment: This still catches me out. Such an obvious solution, too.

Comment: Just a little thing, I had to give width:100% and height:100% to my overflow div.

Comment: And with this, you lose essential relative features like `width: 100%` to the child.

Comment: @m4heshd: Not sure what you mean, works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/1y6gzhw8/. Show a demo of your situation if you want help.

Comment: @thirtydot I think you misunderstood what I stated. Your example works because the element tree is only 2 steps. Take a dropdown menu on a modal. Dropdown gets clipped if the parent is positioned relative and the container has `overflow` set to scroll or hidden. But the dropdown needs input to be `relative` to resize itself to the same size. The `width` is calculated from the first relative parent. There's no solution for this and it's an open issue in CSSWG. Also I solved my issue by writing a really solid solution with JS, specific for my scenario.

Comment: @m4heshd: I didn't "misunderstand", you just didn't explain with enough detail. I'm glad you solved your problem.

Comment: It doesn't work if the elements are inline, e.g., spans inside an anchor element.

Answer (score 19):

The code below works like a charm.

```
<div id="grandparent" style="position:relative;">
    <div id="parent" style="overflow:hidden;">
        <div id="child" style="position:absolute;">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Linking to the [blog article](https://front-back.com/how-to-make-absolute-positioned-elements-overlap-their-overflow-hidden-parent/) that first discovered and explained it is only fair.

Answer (score 7):

The Problem has a Name: "**offsetParent**". As soon as an element gets the position abolute|relative or has its position/size altered by a transformation, it becomes the offsetParent of its children. The original offsetParent for all elements (and therefore the area in which overflowing content will be shown or relative to which absolute positions are given) is the viewport of the browser or the iFrame. But after an absolute or relative position had been applied to an element, ist bounding box is the new origin for positioning and clipping of all of ist children.

In a Project, I had a 'popup' window containing a pulldown menu. The pulldown could easily extend over the limits of the window. But as soon as the window was moved (by using a transformation or relative positioning), the pulldown appeared at a wrong place (having the top-left Position of the window as additional Offset) and was clipped at the window's borders. The quick hack I used was to append the pulldown as child of Body (instead fo the window) and position it absolute, using the coordinates of the button that opens the menu (from the clientBoundingBox of the button) and the offset from the button's offsetParent) as absolute position of the pulldown. Then the Body again was the limiting area. This is, however, a bit tricky if it comes to multiple Levels of z-axis ordering (as the pulldown's z-axis is relative to Body, which might be different from the one the window has). But since the window has to be visible (therefore on top) to open the menu, this was negligible.
Of course, this solution requires the use of JavaScript and cannot be done by simple CSS.

You can't eat the cake ***and*** keep it. If you take something out of the layout context, it becomes ist own, indepenent (and limited) layout 'frame'

Comment: So nice to read an actual explanation of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I usually use overflow:hidden as clearfix. In this case, I give up and just add an additional div.

```
<div id="parent" style="position:relative;">
  <!-- floating divs here -->
  <div id="child" style="position:absolute;"></div>
  <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use css...

```
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

#parent {width: auto; overflow: hidden;}

#child {position: absolute; width: auto;}
```

With width auto it will always append to the smallest possible size; and with the reset it will help maintain natural flow.

But if the child is bigger in any way than the parent, then it will not be possible. But with this CSS I think you will achieve what you want to the maximum of what is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I did this in a very simple way

```
<div class="rootparent">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
</div>

.rootparent {
  position:relative;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
}
.parent {
  overflow:hidden;
}
.child {
   position: absolute;
   top: -10px;
   right: -15px;
   width: 30px;
   height: 30px;
   border: 1px solid red;
}
```

[Here is jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/as88425/5oc8fLjg/3/)

Comment: That answer is not adding anything beyond what [Don's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25194386/1280867) from Aug 8, 2014 already said.

Answer (score -1):

thirtydot's solution is actually a good idea.

Here's a clearer example: http://jsfiddle.net/y9dtL68d/

**HTML**

```
<div id="grandparent">
    <div id="parent">
        <p>this has a lot of content which ...</p>
        <p>this has a lot of content which ...</p>
        <p>this has a lot of content which ...</p>
        <p>this has a lot of content which ...</p>
        <p>this has a lot of content which ...</p>
        <p>this has a lot of content which ...</p>
        <p>this has a lot of content which ...</p>
    </div>
    <div id="child">
        dudes
    </div>    
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#grandparent {
    position: relative;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 20px;
    background: #d0d0d0;
}
#parent {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#child {
    position: absolute;
    background: red;
    color: white;
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I believe, every front-end developer encountered this situation, at least once. Let's say you need to absolute position something… And then you try to move it in some direction, and boom it disappears… You forgot the parent was set to overflow:hidden and now your element is lost in the hidden infinite vacuum.There is a css trick to do this.Please find the below demo example for it...

```
<br><br><br>
<div class="grand-parent">
  <div class="parent">P
    <div class="child">child</div>
  </div>
</div>
css code:


.grand-parent {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  position:relative;
  background-color: grey;
}
.parent {
  width:10px;
  height:30px;
  overflow:hidden;
  background-color: blue;
}
.child {
  position:absolute; 
  width:50px;
  height:20px;
  background-color: red;
  top:-10px; 
  left:5px;
}
```

Comment: That answer is not adding anything beyond what [Don's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25194386/1280867) from Aug 8, 2014 already said.

Comment: Answer is probably plagiarizing this [blog article](https://front-back.com/how-to-make-absolute-positioned-elements-overlap-their-overflow-hidden-parent/)