# How to make a child element visible if the parent is overflow:hidden?

Tags: css, overflow

I have a child element with `overflow:visible;` and the parent element with `overflow:hidden;`. The child element has height higher than the parent element.

Why the child element is hidden if has the property **overflow** set to **visible**?

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="makeThisVisible"></div>
    <div id="thisRemainsHidden"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: Gray;
    /*OVERFLOW*/
    overflow: hidden;
}
#makeThisVisible {
    width: 240px;
    height: 300px;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid red;
    background: IndianRed;
    /*OVERFLOW*/
    overflow: visible;
    margin-left: 8px;
}
#thisRemainsHidden {
    width: 240px;
    height: 300px;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid teal;
    background: DarkCyan;
}
```

The fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ewNbu/

To resolve this issue i don't want to use visibility property for `#container` or position:absolute property for `#makeThisVisible`, but I want to find another better way to solve the problem.

Please help!
Thank you so much.

Comment: I think it's a bit obvious. If the parent is smaller and is set to hide when a child exceeds its size, that's what it's gonna happen.

Comment: Note: `overflow` property describes how the **content** of the matched element will behave, **not the element itself**; as a result, `overflow:visible;` on `#makeThisVisible` won't change its behavior.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Absolute position and Overflow:hidden](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5513382/absolute-position-and-overflowhidden)

Comment: It seems to be impossible. There should exists sth. new like `ignore-parent-overflow: true` :D

Answer (score 13):

You can try playing with:

```
position:absolute;
```

which breaks the child out of the scope of the parent element.

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ewNbu/1/)

Comment: OP Quote : "I don't want to use visibility property for #container or `position:absolute` property for `#makeThisVisible`"

Comment: @Bigood Ooops, missed that one, sorry. Well I think this might however be the only really easy way of doing this, and I don't see a problem with using it.

Comment: Me neither, but the OP explicitly said he didn't want that solution, and is looking for an alternative...

Comment: This only works if the parent does not have position:relative.