# Is it possible to show an inner-div "on top" of a div that is set to overflow:hidden?

Tags: html, css, overflow

Is it possible to show an inner-div "on top" of a div that is set to overflow:hidden?

***Something like:***

```
<div style="position:relative;overflow:hidden;" id="container">
   <div style="position:absolute;left:-15px;width:100px;height:100px;" class="product">product1</div>
   <div class="product-popup">Product1 price etc</div>
   <div style="position:absolute;left:10px;width:100px;height:100px;" class="product">product2</div>
   <div class="product-popup">Product2 price etc</div>
</div>
```

When viewing the page the products are not visible outside the boundaries of the `#container`-div. When I click the div with class `product-popup` I want to show the popup outside the boundaries of `#container`-div. Is this possible?

Comment: Can you make a jsFiddle?

Comment: can you post the code responsible for popping up your div

Comment: possible if used `position: fixed` instead of absolute.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Absolute position and Overflow:hidden](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5513382/absolute-position-and-overflowhidden)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple answer, **you cant.**

If you're setting `overflow:hidden` on the parent, it will do just that to any overflow so so not show the child.

You may need to think about what you're trying to accomplish and why.

In order to correctly show child content outside the defined boundaries of a parent, consider giving the parent fixed height/width (optional) with a position of `relative`. The child should be positioned absolutely within this, but can be placed outside its limits. It will display as long as `overflow:hidden` isnt set on the parent, and the child's position remains within the browser viewport.

See this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/vSYKC/2/) for examples of how overflow and positioning work together.

If you're desperate to maintain `overflow:hidden` on the content within your container, simply nest another wrapper within it, e.g.

## [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/3D5JG/)

HTML

```
<div class='parent'>
    <div class='content'>content
        <br>content
        <br>content
        <br>content
        <br>content
        <br>content
        <br>content
        <br>content
        <br>content
        <br>content
        <br>content
        <br>content
        <br>content
        <br>content
        <br>content
        <br>content
        <br>content
        <br>content
        <br>content
        <br>content
        <br>content
        <br>
    </div>
    <div class='popup'></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
    padding:50px;
}
.parent {
    position:relative;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
.content {
    overflow:hidden;
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    border:1px solid blue;
}
.popup {
    top:-20px;
    left:-20px;
    height:20px;
    width:20px;
    position:absolute;
    border:1px solid green;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I suspected it was like this, but maybe, maybe it could be some solution out there. I would have to rearrange my html where the popups would reside outside the containter for the actual products.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to "force" something to be displayed outside a overflow:hidden container.

You would need to rearrange the html. As you are using a click event (JS?) you could place the popups somewhere else and just show them with JS.

Answer (score 0):

As @Mr_Green pointed out in the comments, this is possible, if you set position:fixed to the inner div

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/msUP9/1/)**

```
<div class="outer">outer
    <div class="inner">
        inner
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.outer
{
    margin: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: yellow;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.inner
{
    margin: 10px;
    width: 300px;
    position:fixed;
    height: 50px;
    background: pink;
}
```

That being said, I realize that using position fixed isn't feasible in many cases.