# Overflow, is not working when positioned absolute.

Tags: html, css

I have a div positioned relative and inside it there is another div positioned absolute. 
I have gave the main div overflow:hidden and also border-radios... however, the edge of the div inside are not covered inside the main one, i.e the overflow is not working.

Live preview and full code here: http://jsfiddle.net/sYv78

```
<div class="gridElement">
    <img alt="image" src=
    "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/441318694942031872/I2cc6yMB.jpeg">

    <div class="animate">
        <p>Short Description</p>
    </div><a href=""></a>
</div>

.frames img, .frame {
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
}
/*Grids System*/
 .grids {
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
    -moz-column-gap: 10px;
    column-gap: 10px;
}
.grids.columns2 {
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
}
.grids.columns4 {
    -webkit-column-count: 4;
    -moz-column-count: 4;
    column-count: 4;
}
.grids .gridElement {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.grids .gridElement:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.grids .gridElement img {
    min-width: 100%;
}
.grids .gridElement .animate {
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding-top: 20%;
    text-align: center;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all .4s linear;
    -moz-transition: all .4s linear;
    -o-transition: all .4s linear;
    transition: all .4s linear;
}
.grids .gridElement:hover > .animate {
    filter: alpha(opacity=1);
    opacity: 1;
}
.grids .gridElement .animate span.background {
    background-color: #3F8AE4;
    filter: alpha(opacity=70);
    opacity: 0.70;
}
.grids .gridElement .animate span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding-top: 20%;
    font-size: 2em;
}
.grids .gridElement a {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.grids .gridElement a * {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.grids .gridElement .animate p {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding: 0 15px 15px 0;
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear

Comment: Try and hover over the gridElemtns in the example, see how the blue div inside them show up and its edges are not hidden within the parent div frame? as the main div has border-radios and it is rounded corners. Don't understand why overflow isn't working

Comment: I think you have a typo in your css, It should be `.frames` and not `.frame`

Comment: @AbhasTandon no that is correct mate, it is a bit complex how it works, but it is correct.

Comment: Are you sure it's correct. I am talking about first line of your css. Because I don't see even a single element with class `frame` in your html. You have used class `frameS` though. btw read this answers once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5513382/absolute-position-and-overflowhidden and make sure that what you are trying is not impossible.

Answer (score 0):

The strange thing about `overflow: hidden;` is that it needs fixed boundaries to work. By specifying a fixed height for the `.grids .gridElement` class like `500px` , the overflow remained hidden :)

Comment: The .frames were added to the wrong div, that was the problem. Thank you anyway mate!