# CSS overflow: hidden ignored

Tags: html, css

I am struggling to understand, why overflow: hidden is overridden by descendent element. Please check the this example I have created http://jsfiddle.net/2fRxc/.

**HTML**

```
<div class="relative">
    <div class="overflow">box with "overflow:hidden;" (HOVER ME)
        <div class="absolute">absolute box which ignore "overflow:hidden;" rule of parent box</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Style.css**

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
}
.relative {
    position:relative;
    padding:20px;
    width:50%;
    height:50%;
    background:blue;
}
.overflow {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:#ff0;
    overflow:hidden;
    float:left;
}
.overflow:hover .absolute {
    opacity:1
}
.absolute {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:#f00;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    opacity:0
}
```

I know if you apply position relative to the **overflow** container. that will fix it, but I do not want it. I want the the absolute container to be position to relative container.

Any suggestion will be really appreciated.

Comment: "I know if you apply position relative to the overflow container. that will fix it" If you know this, I don't see why you'd struggle to understand what is happening.

Comment: Basically, yeah, what BoltClock said :D The `absolute` element is relative to the `relative` element, it is removed from the flow of elements in between, which means it doesn't follow `overflow` anymore (because it's not flowing in the first place)

Comment: @BolClock, Yeah right, I know but I want a fix for it. I have kind of structure set, which works great for me. I am looking for solution, if there is any?

Comment: I have now updated fiddler demo. This is how my structure looks like.

Comment: @JAML [This trick might help](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5513717/2260614)..!!

Answer (score 0):

### 1st solution

Set the "overflow" div as relative and remove the `float:left` property :

```
.overflow {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:#ff0;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

Here is a demo : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2fRxc/1/)

### 2nd solution

You know you have 20px padding so you define the 4 bounds of your absolute element (and don't specify `height` and `width` properties):

```
.absolute {
    background:#f00;
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    left:20px;
    bottom:20px;
    right:20px;
    opacity:0
}
```

Here is a demo : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2fRxc/4/)

Comment: Hi @Apolo thanks for your response, as I mentioned I do not want the relative position on overflow DIV.

Comment: ok, I will try to find another way. I let this answer here, it could be useful for someone else.

Comment: @JAML : new solution added

Comment: the absolute left and top should be 0 not 20px;

Comment: no, it must be the same value as the top parent padding

Comment: If you put 0... you gonna have a bad time ! :)

Comment: Yes I know :-). But I can't seem to find any good solution for that. that's why I posted this question, if there is anything which can fix it.

Comment: Can you explain why you have such restrictions ? (no relative position, elements floated etc.)

Comment: Maybe I could find other solutions

Answer (score -3):

```
.relative{
    position:relative;
    width: 200px;
}
.overflow{
    width:300px;
    height:20px;
    background:#ff0;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.overflow:hover .absolute{
    opacity:1
}
.absolute{
    background:#f00;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    opacity:0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/88fYK/438/

Comment: I have updated Jsfiddler demo, there you might be able to see what is happening. http://jsfiddle.net/2fRxc/

Comment: Try not to post just "here's your code, pal" answers.