# Absolute division hides behind overflowed div

Tags: html, css, owl-carousel

I have some problem regarding CSS. You can check the following link:

http://lookdemo.biz/webs/chirag/mickes_figurer/

In that you will find the slider under this text "NYFÖDDA FIGURER". I'm currently using owl-carousel for that. Currently the main issue is the blackbox under first item. I mean this:

[image]

This box is hidden under that overflow owl-carousel slider. And this div is absolute. And it should be like this:

[image]

I tried some of the suggestions but it didn't work.

Help is appreciated.

Comment: YOu just your html slider code because your lising is inder slider code and your slider parent define overflow hidden so than you just remove your listing code and put the after slide code

Comment: Thats ok can u share your code only slider or create a fiddle than i can help you only sharing your slider code with listing

Comment: Actually its a big mess lots of images and I am not able to make fiddle for it. Is it possible for you to directly make changes by editing in chrome inspect?

Comment: @RohitAzad is it okay for you buddy?

Comment: try adding `position:relative` to div.sub_hash

Comment: Yes in this way it will work but I want it out of that box. Making that div relative will make it inside it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Absolute position and Overflow:hidden](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5513382/absolute-position-and-overflowhidden)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get this by css only, You have to use Javascript or Jquery for achive this,

for Ex.

css :

```
// css for black box
.blackBox{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
}
```

html :

```
<body>
    <div class="blackBox"></div>
    <div class="slider">
        // slider code
    </div>
</body>
```

Javascript :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // Click event for your hash
        $("#someId").click(function(){
            var top = $(this).offset().top;
            var left = $(this).offset().left;
            $(".blackBox").offset({top: top, left: left}).css("display","block");
        })
    });
</script>
```

hope this will help you...

Comment: Thanks @arjun your solution seems to be worked. Thanks again man ;)