# JS Image Compare button overflow

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been editing this [JS image compare](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_image_compare) example, and everything is great. I just don't know how to change one thing.

The circle button that indicates where the user should drag the image overflows out of the container when its pulled left or right. I'm talking about this: https://prnt.sc/ja1r6g

How can I fix that and make it so that when it's pulled all the way to the right or left, it goes below the image and doesn't show the overflow?

Here's the snipped of the code:

```js
function initComparisons() {
  var x, i;
  /*find all elements with an "overlay" class:*/
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("img-comp-overlay");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    /*once for each "overlay" element:
    pass the "overlay" element as a parameter when executing the compareImages function:*/
    compareImages(x[i]);
  }
  function compareImages(img) {
    var slider, img, clicked = 0, w, h;
    /*get the width and height of the img element*/
    w = img.offsetWidth;
    h = img.offsetHeight;
    /*set the width of the img element to 50%:*/
    img.style.width = (w / 2) + "px";
    /*create slider:*/
    slider = document.createElement("DIV");
    slider.setAttribute("class", "img-comp-slider");
    /*insert slider*/
    img.parentElement.insertBefore(slider, img);
    /*position the slider in the middle:*/
    slider.style.top = (h / 2) - (slider.offsetHeight / 2) + "px";
    slider.style.left = (w / 2) - (slider.offsetWidth / 2) + "px";
    /*execute a function when the mouse button is pressed:*/
    slider.addEventListener("mousedown", slideReady);
    /*and another function when the mouse button is released:*/
    window.addEventListener("mouseup", slideFinish);
    /*or touched (for touch screens:*/
    slider.addEventListener("touchstart", slideReady);
    /*and released (for touch screens:*/
    window.addEventListener("touchstop", slideFinish);
    function slideReady(e) {
      /*prevent any other actions that may occur when moving over the image:*/
      e.preventDefault();
      /*the slider is now clicked and ready to move:*/
      clicked = 1;
      /*execute a function when the slider is moved:*/
      window.addEventListener("mousemove", slideMove);
      window.addEventListener("touchmove", slideMove);
    }
    function slideFinish() {
      /*the slider is no longer clicked:*/
      clicked = 0;
    }
    function slideMove(e) {
      var pos;
      /*if the slider is no longer clicked, exit this function:*/
      if (clicked == 0) return false;
      /*get the cursor's x position:*/
      pos = getCursorPos(e)
      /*prevent the slider from being positioned outside the image:*/
      if (pos < 0) pos = 0;
      if (pos > w) pos = w;
      /*execute a function that will resize the overlay image according to the cursor:*/
      slide(pos);
    }
    function getCursorPos(e) {
      var a, x = 0;
      e = e || window.event;
      /*get the x positions of the image:*/
      a = img.getBoundingClientRect();
      /*calculate the cursor's x coordinate, relative to the image:*/
      x = e.pageX - a.left;
      /*consider any page scrolling:*/
      x = x - window.pageXOffset;
      return x;
    }
    function slide(x) {
      /*resize the image:*/
      img.style.width = x + "px";
      /*position the slider:*/
      slider.style.left = img.offsetWidth - (slider.offsetWidth / 2) + "px";
    }
  }
}

initComparisons();
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
.img-comp-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px; /*should be the same height as the images*/
}
.img-comp-img {
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.img-comp-img img {
  display:block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
.img-comp-slider {
  position: absolute;
  z-index:9;
  cursor: ew-resize;
  /*set the appearance of the slider:*/
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  opacity: 0.7;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<h1>Compare Two Images</h1>

<p>Click and slide the blue slider to compare two images:</p>

<div class="img-comp-container">
  <div class="img-comp-img">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/animals" width="300" height="200">
  </div>
  <div class="img-comp-img img-comp-overlay">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/animals?t=1524676145713" width="300" height="200">
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**: If I just add another div to wrap it all in and add overflow: hidden, it doesn't actually DO anything.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Absolute position and Overflow:hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5513382/absolute-position-and-overflowhidden)

Comment: If I just add another div to wrap it all in and add overflow: hidden, it doesn't actually do anything.

Comment: You are right. It is different scenario. I like this tricky question. So hopefully I will be able to help soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've got a solution. Pretty simple one. But you must know the width of your `.img-comp-container`. And of course `overflow: hidden;` is there as well

The problem is, that `overflow: hidden;` works as it should. But since your `.img-comp-container` is a block style element it spans the whole width of your webpage (or its parent container). Therefore to enforce the overflow not just vertically but also horizontally, you have to limit the width of that div to "hide" it properly

```js
function initComparisons() {
  var x, i;
  /*find all elements with an "overlay" class:*/
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("img-comp-overlay");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    /*once for each "overlay" element:
    pass the "overlay" element as a parameter when executing the compareImages function:*/
    compareImages(x[i]);
  }

  function compareImages(img) {
    var slider, img, clicked = 0,
      w, h;
    /*get the width and height of the img element*/
    w = img.offsetWidth;
    h = img.offsetHeight;
    /*set the width of the img element to 50%:*/
    img.style.width = (w / 2) + "px";
    /*create slider:*/
    slider = document.createElement("DIV");
    slider.setAttribute("class", "img-comp-slider");
    /*insert slider*/
    img.parentElement.insertBefore(slider, img);
    /*position the slider in the middle:*/
    slider.style.top = (h / 2) - (slider.offsetHeight / 2) + "px";
    slider.style.left = (w / 2) - (slider.offsetWidth / 2) + "px";
    /*execute a function when the mouse button is pressed:*/
    slider.addEventListener("mousedown", slideReady);
    /*and another function when the mouse button is released:*/
    window.addEventListener("mouseup", slideFinish);
    /*or touched (for touch screens:*/
    slider.addEventListener("touchstart", slideReady);
    /*and released (for touch screens:*/
    window.addEventListener("touchstop", slideFinish);

    function slideReady(e) {
      /*prevent any other actions that may occur when moving over the image:*/
      e.preventDefault();
      /*the slider is now clicked and ready to move:*/
      clicked = 1;
      /*execute a function when the slider is moved:*/
      window.addEventListener("mousemove", slideMove);
      window.addEventListener("touchmove", slideMove);
    }

    function slideFinish() {
      /*the slider is no longer clicked:*/
      clicked = 0;
    }

    function slideMove(e) {
      var pos;
      /*if the slider is no longer clicked, exit this function:*/
      if (clicked == 0) return false;
      /*get the cursor's x position:*/
      pos = getCursorPos(e)
      /*prevent the slider from being positioned outside the image:*/
      if (pos < 0) pos = 0;
      if (pos > w) pos = w;
      /*execute a function that will resize the overlay image according to the cursor:*/
      slide(pos);
    }

    function getCursorPos(e) {
      var a, x = 0;
      e = e || window.event;
      /*get the x positions of the image:*/
      a = img.getBoundingClientRect();
      /*calculate the cursor's x coordinate, relative to the image:*/
      x = e.pageX - a.left;
      /*consider any page scrolling:*/
      x = x - window.pageXOffset;
      return x;
    }

    function slide(x) {
      /*resize the image:*/
      img.style.width = x + "px";
      /*position the slider:*/
      slider.style.left = img.offsetWidth - (slider.offsetWidth / 2) + "px";
    }
  }
}

initComparisons();
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.img-comp-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  /*should be the same height as the images*/
  /* Overflow must be here, and helping it up with width */
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.img-comp-img {
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.img-comp-img img {
  display: block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.img-comp-slider {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  cursor: ew-resize;
  /*set the appearance of the slider:*/
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  opacity: 0.7;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<h1>Compare Two Images</h1>

<p>Click and slide the blue slider to compare two images:</p>

<div class="img-comp-container">
  <div class="img-comp-img">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/animals" width="300" height="200">
  </div>
  <div class="img-comp-img img-comp-overlay">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/animals?t=1524676145713" width="300" height="200">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah yeah, that makes sense! Thank you so much, Ludovit! This solved my problem.