# Display a div with position absolute

Tags: css, reactjs

Basically I have 3 divs with the following structure

> < div>
>
> < ul>
>
> < li>

and inside my li I have a div with position absolute, but I'm not able to display it on the screen
I already tried to leave the last parent as relative but I couldn't

problem on gif:

[image]

**code:**

```
const Side = styled.div`
  width: 75px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #3c8dbc;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
  & .brand {
    height: 65px;
    background: orange;
  }
  & .aside_footer {
    height: 100px;
    background: hotpink;
  }
`;
const WrapScrollable = styled.div`
  height: calc(100% - 165px);
  overflow: ${props => (props.isHover ? "hidden" : "scroll")};
  background: orange;
  ul {
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
    position: relative;
  }
`;

const Litem = styled("li")`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: hotpink;
  position: relative;
`;

const Dropdown = styled.div`
  display: block;
  max-height: 400px !important;
  max-width: 400px !important;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  top: 0;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  font-weight: 400;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0px;
  z-index: 2;
  background: orange;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
`;
// sideBar
const SideBar = () => {
  const [isHover, setisHover] = React.useState(false);
  console.log(isHover);
  return (
    <Side>
      <div className="brand">Logo</div>
      <WrapScrollable isHover={isHover}>
        <ul>
          <Litem
            onMouseOver={() => setisHover(true)}
            onMouseOut={() => setisHover(false)}
          >
            <button type="button">show/hide dropdown</button>
            <Dropdown>dropdown content</Dropdown>
          </Litem>
        </ul>
      </WrapScrollable>
      <div className="aside_footer">footer</div>
    </Side>
  );
};
```

example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-matsumoto-b37pu?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Your problem is `overlow:hidden;`. Either remove that entirely, or remove the style on hover/click.

Answer (score -1):

You should remove the transform: translateX(100%); this is moving your div element to the right, your code should look like this:

```
const Side = styled.div`
  width: 75px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #3c8dbc;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  & .brand {
    height: 65px;
    background: orange;
  }
  & .aside_footer {
    height: 100px;
    background: hotpink;
  }
`;
const WrapScrollable = styled.div`
  height: calc(100vh - 165px);
  overflow: ${props => (props.isHover ? "hidden" : "scroll")};
  background: orange;
  ul {
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
    position: relative;
  }
`;

const Litem = styled("li")`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: hotpink;
  position: relative;
`;

const Dropdown = styled.div`
  display: block;
  max-height: 400px !important;
  max-width: 400px !important;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  top: 0;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  font-weight: 400;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0px;
  z-index: 2;
  background: orange;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
`;
// sideBar
const SideBar = () => {
  const [isHover, setisHover] = React.useState(false);
  console.log(isHover);
  return (
    <Side>
      <div className="brand">Logo</div>
       <div class="content-container">
        <div class="menu-container">
            <ul>
          <Litem
            onMouseOver={() => setisHover(true)}
            onMouseOut={() => setisHover(false)}
          >
            <button type="button">show/hide dropdown</button>
            <Dropdown>dropdown content</Dropdown>
          </Litem>
        </ul>
        </div>
      <WrapScrollable isHover={isHover}>

      </WrapScrollable>
</div>
      <div className="aside_footer">footer</div>
    </Side>
  );
};
```

Comment: I need my element to appear outside my sidebar so I moved it to the right

Comment: then remove the overflow: ${props => (props.isHover ? "hidden" : "scroll")}; from WrapScrollable. and you should add overflow to a child component: ```<div id="parent">
    <div><ul><li></li></ul></div>
<WrapScrollable>
</div>```

Comment: can ue dit awnser? i dont understand i put overflow because i need scroll on my scrollable div.

Comment: You can't use overflow with position absolute, you can check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5513382/absolute-position-and-overflowhidden

Comment: because this i use overflow hidden on hover, this dont work ;\

Comment: now it should work you have overflow:hidden on Side too.